# Are there any mOhm resistors that can be used without PCBs?

Tags: resistors, oscillator, resistance, components

I am just a curious electronics hobbyist and enthusiast that wants to build an oscillator circuit for fun and to learn how it works.

---

**What I need**

1. A resistor that has a resistance value of 1 mOhm or less
2. That has wire leads and not solder joints
3. That can be used without being put on a PCB

---

Does anyone know a resistor or a family of resistors that can meet these requirements?

Finding a resistor that meets these requirements proves quite difficult and I have spent about a few days searching for one.

I have looked at Mouser's and Digikey's websites, along with other websites, but to no avail. They only have resistors like [these](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/ohmite/MCS3264R050FER/2003884?utm_adgroup=Chip%20Resistor%20-%20Surface%20Mount&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Shopping_Product_Resistors_NEW&utm_term=&productid=2003884&gclid=Cj0KCQjwkZiFBhD9ARIsAGxFX8AzJasPuNx0nT6pgx-wdU-gKxsjsF_1ojv2eekQzlMyV-t6ugDvA2IaAsRQEALw_wcB), which require to be attached to a PCB and soldered. That does not work for me because the subject of PCBs is dull to me.

I just hope I am not asking for to much.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need one? What is the circuit? The lead connections will be much more than 1 milliOhm. There is no point having a one milliohm resistor with just two wire leads.

Comment: Cut the leads of a 1/4 W resistor. Throw the resistor body away. Now you have two m\$\Omega\$ resistors. More seriously, with a data sheet to give you the wire diameter and an online calculator you should be able to work out the actual resistance.

Comment: @KevinWhite I want to experiment with different resistance values (5 ohms, 150 ohms, 1kOhms, etc) to get an understanding of oscillator circuits. I don't really have a specific circuit in mind as I am exploring my options right now. I need this kind of resistor because I want to have an understanding of the whole range of resistances, from large resistances to very small ones when they are applied to the circuit. My ask is, do you know about any resistors that I am looking for? Even one that is close.

Comment: Just do a basic RC time constant calculation and you'll see that low value resistors are useless for an oscillator. In addition, you won't be able to generate a high enough voltage across them to sustain an oscillation. Their most common use would be as a current shunt.

Comment: Oscillator circuits typically depend only on the ratio of resistances and use values in the range of 1K to 1 Meg. There's no need to use milliohm resistors.

Comment: what kind of oscillator uses 1 mohm resistor with LC parts without similar DCR,ESR ? ? Answer? switched mode power supply that is self-resonant?  ( but horribly regulated)  But otherwise. Hint Lookup hookup wire AWG tables

Comment: For a better understanding   search RLC nomograph and look for my answers that show how to choose Q and SRF

Comment: As @transistor says, the resistance of the component leads and typical hook-up wire will be in the milliohm range, so there is no point in making leaded resistors with such low values.  The resistance of #22 copper wire is about 1.3 milliOhms per inch.

Comment: Get a zero ohm resistor. It's at least 1mOhm.

Comment: Shocked, it's been said to your last question about capacitors: the smaller component values are, the larger parasitic effects. You can't work with milliohm-range resistances without a reliable way of connecting them together. A PCB is by far the easiest way to achieve that.

Comment: Also, before experimenting with oscillators, you should try a little harder to build up an understanding of what you're doing. Building oscillators with milliohm resistors makes no sense, and that answer should have lead to more research on your side instead of the next question about leaded components. By the way, in case your next question is about yet another low value component with leads: exact same answer. Parasitics larger than intended value. Can't do it like that.

Comment: Thank you for your input @mmmm. Yes, I will admit, I started learning about electronics recently from Khan academy, Practical electronics for inventors and the art of electronics textbooks. I probably need to learn some more before I make any big circuits.

Comment: Just some advice from another self educating hobbyist, if you want good first projects, work on DC/DC switching voltage converters.  By nature they have a simple-to-complicated analog/digital control side and a simple-to-complicated power circuit.  You'll end up needing voltage converters for pretty much everything, and because of the wide range of difficulty levels you can start simple and learn in bite sized pieces.  Study a fixed load buck converter, then add components to make it regulate over variable load, then try your hand at boost conversion and buck/boost.

Comment: To build a buck converter, you need to learn to select resistors, an inductor, capacitors, and a switch.  You also need some sort of oscillator to drive it, which could be anything from a simple and easy to set up 555 timer to some product of your current oscillator experiment.  You can learn about comparators and Op amps to improve your control circuit, and hopefully you see the idea that it's a project simple enough that a hobbyist can break it down into manageable parts.  You can incorporate a microcontroller to simplify further or learn some analog control.

Comment: @KH Thank you for your advice, I will consider it. Yes, it is tough for a self-educating hobbyist to find a good first project and it is difficult to get the right practice as well, I would say.

Comment: My personal bias is that I know some programming, which makes digital logic circuits easy unless they're high speed, electrician training, which includes fundamentals like resistance, capacitors, inductors, sine wave AC, DC circuits and a lot of EE-related bonus material like control circuits, rotary machines, so I should have mentioned start with Ohm's Law, Watt's Law, series/parallel resistance, edison 3 wire, capacitance, inductance in your actual theory education.  Those skills can be applied to simple projects to develop further skills.

Comment: _" the subject of PCBs is dull to me"_ - how do you intend to connect your components into the circuit?

Comment: Oh good catch Bruce I didn't notice that line.  OP, you should actually try a simple 2 layer PCB with a free program like EAGLE before you conclude it's boring.  Advanced PCB design is painstaking and involves a lot of finicky engineering skills, but for your first easy projects, getting everything routed is not only fairly easy and intuitive (the autorouter can get you started) but kind of fun taking it's suggestion and turning it into something aesthetically pleasing.  With modern batching services, for simple projects, you can have easy, inexpensive and professional looking bundled up.

Comment: The only practical resistors I have seen in the miliOhm range are current-sense resistors (for current sense amplifiers or for switch-mode power supplies). These always use 4-wire Kelvin connection: one pair of wires carries the current, and a different pair of wires measures the differential voltage. Most mOhm resistors for this application are surface-mount (EIA 2512 is a common size). The only non-surface-mount types I have seen are the non-inductive, ceramic-filled types that actually have 4 leads.

Comment: When you graph the parameters, you'll understand the math, and only then will you understand why mOhm is too small. (Look at the Nomograph in Tony's answer, and make your own.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*1 milliohm added to an oscillator would be like pee in the ocean and expecting it to rise.*

Series RLC circuits have a Q resonant gain of reactive impedance **$$Qs=X(f)/Rs$$**  using either L or C when the lines intersect.

I chose Rs and Qs designations for clarity to indicate series.

Thus is X(f)=1k and Rs=10 then Q= 100 or in other words Rs is 2 decades or 40 dB=100:1 below X intersection of selected L,C.

Parallel RLC circuits or "tank circuits" only by logic diagram appearance and certainly not impedance as they are very high and equal to Rp at resonance and X(L) cancels with X(C) but **$$Qp=Rp/X(f)$$** which also defines f/BW (-3dB) and passive gain at resonance.  Q's > 100 are rare.

For dielectric Caps used as line bridge filters, Dissipation Factor (D.F.) as a loss ratio at 120Hz is like the inverse of Q but standardize as 2f for 60Hz.  The low ESR caps are rated in ESR instead of D.F.

This is like an old fashion static slide rule. With 6 variables R,L,C,f, Q & Z. You can solve for the unknown by the intersection and ratio above Rs or below Rp.

[image]

[See RLC nomograph application](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/431122/measure-impedance-of-rectifier-using-harmonic-balance-in-ads-software/431132#431132)

You can add paper at the bottom and to the right and still use mohms and GHz but with physical limitations of parts in mind. (like ESL, ESR, DCR parasitics)

Comment: "1 milliohm added to an oscillator would be like pee in the ocean and expecting it to rise.", but why is it like that? What makes a milliohm resistor so bad in an oscillator? It cannot sustain the oscillation or something like that?

Comment: It’s not bad, it’s not useful. No need for mohm in an Osc. That has an Rs in Ohms.

Comment: Why is it not useful? What exactly makes a mOhm resistor not useful in an oscillator? I am just trying to understand for the sake of learning.

Comment: What happens when you add 1mOhm to 10 ohms?(nothing). However they are useful as current shunts with 50mV drop at desired max current